# adding ng-Controller to a div is removing values from options within a select list generated from server

Tags: html, angularjs, jsf

I'm using a jsf select

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="modifierList" valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.MailingAddressForm.changeOfModifier}" value="#{pageFlowScope.MailingAddressForm.modifier}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{pageFlowScope.MailingAddressForm.modifierList}" id="si1"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

when I place that code within

```
<div ng-controller="anyController">

</div>
```

the select list options have the text, but the value is removed. Each and every option within every drpodown within the div, has this happening.

```
<option value>Some Text</option>
```

as opposed to

```
 <option value="foo">Some Text</option>
```

when I remove the ng-controller attribute, the html for the dropdown is correct, but I of course cannot use the functionality within the controller. What am I doing wrong here? I've not seen this behavior before nor was I able to find anyone else with this same issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the generated output from JSF as HTML? Are there any $scope properties in /anyController/ that could be overwriting the values in the dropdown?

Comment: did you get through this? how?